# ¿Como puedo imprimir en pantalla este Array en PHP?

Tags: php, array

Me han dejado el siguiente ejercicio en PHP y no tengo idea de cómo debo imprimir correctamente en pantalla este Array, según el ejercicio, debo imprimirlo usando preferiblemente Foreach, ¡Gracias de antemano!

```
    <?php
$productos=array(
     "chocorramo"=>[
     "nombre_producto"=>"Chocorramo",
     "descripcion"=>[
            "empresa"=>[
                    "ramo"=>[
                        "direccion"=>"carrera 30 sur 56 y 2",
                        "oficina"=>"313",
                        "director"=>"Rafael pardo",
                        "fecha_fundacion"=>"26 agosto 1980"
                    ] /*end ramo*/
                        ] /*end empresa*/ ,
                "tabla_nutricional"=>[
                "carbohidratos"=>[
                    "carbohidratos"=>"37g",
                    "fibra_dietetica"=>"3g",
                    "azucar"=>"22g"
                ] /*end carbohidratos */ ,
                "grasas"=>[
                    "grasas"=>"16g",
                    "saturadas"=>"11g",
                    "Poliinsaturados"=>"1g",
                    "Monoinsaturados"=>"3g",
                    "trans"=>"--g"
                ] /* end grasas */,
                "proteinas"=>[
                   "proteinas"=>"4g",
                   "sodio"=>"85mg",
                   "potasio"=>"--mg",
                   "colesterol"=>"30mg"
                ] /*end proteinas */,
                "vitaminas"=>[
                    "vitamina_a"=>"--%",
                    "vitamina_c"=>"--%",
                    "calcio"=>"4%",
                    "hierro"=>"8%"
                ] /*end vitaminas */
                                    ]

                ], /* end descripcion*/
                "lote"=>[
                    "id_lote"=>"0-8737-993",
                    "vencimiento"=>"12-08-2019",
                    "enbase"=>"12-01-2019"    

                ],/* end lote */
                "dimensiones"=>[
                    "ancho"=>"7",
                    "alto"=>"15",
                    "peso"=>"50g"
                ], /*end dimensiones */
                "textos"=>[
                    "1"=>"Los porcentajes están basados en una dieta de 2000 calorías al día."
                ]
    ]
); 
?>
```

Se supone que debo hacerlo mediante la función Foreach, pero no tengo idea de si únicamente debo añadir uno o varios y además no sé como estructurar dicho foreach.
Si me podéis ayudar, os agradecería muchísimo. 
Nuevamente, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Poné un ejemplo de la salida que pretendes obtener.

Comment: Imagino que cuando dices "imprimir correctamente en pantalla" te refieres a "mostrar correctamente en unan tabla en una página web", ¿me equivoco? ¿Sólo un registro como ese o varios? Si nos confirmas esos detalles podremos ayudarte.

Answer (score 4):

Con una función Recursiva solucionarias el problema de manera sencilla:

```
function FuncionRecursiva($arreglo){

    foreach ($arreglo as $nombre => $valor){ //Dividimos el arreglo en niveles por decirlo de una manera

        if (is_array($valor)){ // si el segundo nivel es un arreglo

            echo "<strong>".$nombre."</strong><br>"; //imprime el key de ese nivel
            FuncionRecursiva($valor);                // y se manda a llamar a si misma
        }

        else{ // sino imprime la key y su valor             
            echo "&nbsp".$nombre . " = " . $valor . "<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

Y entonces mandas a llamar la función así:

```
echo FuncionRecursiva($productos);
```

Y el resultado seria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muy elegante ^^

Answer (score 0):

Te comento lo siguiente:

- El vector tiene niveles de profundidad en algunas de sus claves
- Traté de iterar sobre todo su *vector* con `foreach` anidados sin resultados positivos
- Separé el acceso a cada una de las claves de tu vector en variables por separado
- Cada variable accedemos a los elementos contenidos, por medio de los nombres de clave que poseen con esta sintaxis: `["clave1"]["sub-clave1"]["sub-claveclaven"]....`, en este apartado se usan todas las claves que estan contenidas a su vez en una clave padre, así hasta descender al valor deseado
- Cada variable puede tener un solo elemento o múltiples de ellos por lo tanto en algunos es necesario utilizar un bucle `foreach` y en otros con imprimir el valor de la clave bastará.

Entonces el código debería verse de este modo:

```
echo "Título principal"."\n";
echo $productos["chocorramo"]["nombre_producto"];
echo "\n";
echo "\n";
$ramo          = $productos["chocorramo"]["descripcion"]["empresa"]["ramo"];
$carbohidratos = $productos["chocorramo"]["descripcion"]["tabla_nutricional"]["carbohidratos"];
$grasas        = $productos["chocorramo"]["descripcion"]["tabla_nutricional"]["grasas"];
$vitaminas     = $productos["chocorramo"]["descripcion"]["tabla_nutricional"]["vitaminas"];
$lote          = $productos["chocorramo"]["lote"];
$dimensiones   = $productos["chocorramo"]["dimensiones"];
$textos        = $productos["chocorramo"]["textos"];
```

Impresión de los valores (si solo existe un elemento en algunas variables se omite el uso de `foreach` y en las variables que contienen múltiples si será requerido)

```
echo "RAMOS"."\n";
foreach($ramo as $ramo1) {
    echo $ramo1."\n";
}

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "CARBOHIDRATOS"."\n";
foreach($carbohidratos as $carbohidrato) {
    echo $carbohidrato."\n";
}

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "GRASAS"."\n";
foreach($grasas as $grasa) {
    echo $grasa."\n";
}

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "VITAMINAS"."\n";
foreach($vitaminas as $vitamina) {
    echo $vitamina."\n";
}

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "DIMENSIONES"."\n";
foreach($dimensiones as $dimension) {
    echo $dimension."\n";
}

echo "\n";
echo "\n";

echo "TEXTOS"."\n";
foreach($textos as $texto) {
    echo $texto."\n";
}
```

Resultado en consola:

```
Título principal
Chocorramo1

RAMOS
carrera 30 sur 56 y 2
313
Rafael pardo
26 agosto 1980


CARBOHIDRATOS
37g
3g
22g


GRASAS
16g
11g
1g
3g
--g


VITAMINAS
--%
--%
4%
8%


DIMENSIONES
7
15
50g


TEXTOS
Los porcentajes están basados en una dieta de 2000 calorías al día.
```

- Puedes comprobar que separar a tu vector principal en vectores mas pequeños permite una lectura y acceso a propiedades de manera mas simple y ordenada
  Si tienes dudas sobre como lucen las variables: *$cabohidratos, $grasas, $vitaminas, etc*, puedes hacer lo siguiente a cada una:

Código:

```
var_dump($carbohidratos);
```

Obteniendo esto como resultado:

```
array(3) {
  ["carbohidratos"]=>
  string(3) "37g"
  ["fibra_dietetica"]=>
  string(2) "3g"
  ["azucar"]=>
  string(3) "22g"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Con un anidamiento de `foreach()` podrías acceder a cada uno de los valores de cada uno de los `array`. La clave está en determinar si el campo a iterar se trata de un `array` y de ser así montar un nuevo `foreach` para iterar en el siguiente nivel de profundidad. De no ser un `array` lo único que quedaría por hacerle es un `echo` directamente para sacar su valor.

Una fácil manera de determinar esto es a través de la función `is_array()`.

**PHP**

```
foreach ($productos as $producto) {
    if (is_array($producto)) {
        foreach($producto as $categoria) {
            if (is_array($categoria)) {
                foreach($categoria as $subcategoria) {
                    if (is_array($subcategoria)) {
                        foreach($subcategoria as $subsubcategoria) {
                            if (is_array($subsubcategoria)) {
                                foreach($subsubcategoria as $subsubsubcategoria) {
                                    echo $subsubsubcategoria . '<br>';
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo $subcategoria . '<br>';    
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo $categoria . '<br>';   
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $producto;
    }
}
```

**Salida**

```
Chocorramo
carrera 30 sur 56 y 2
313
Rafael pardo
26 agosto 1980
37g
3g
22g
16g
11g
1g
3g
--g
4g
85mg
--mg
30mg
--%
--%
4%
8%
0-8737-993
12-08-2019
12-01-2019
7
15
50g
Los porcentajes están basados en una dieta de 2000 calorías al día.
```

Si quisieras imprimir también las claves de cada pareja de datos *clave/valor* existe una manera de trabajar con los `foreach()` y que nos permite tratar a la clave y al valor independientemente en vez de como un conjunto.

**PHP**

```
foreach ($productos as $clave1 => $valor1) {
    if (is_array($valor1)) {
        echo '<strong>' . $clave1 . '</strong><br>';
        foreach($valor1 as $clave2 => $valor2) {
            if (is_array($valor2)) {
                echo '<strong>' . $clave2 . '</strong><br>';
                foreach($valor2 as $clave3 => $valor3) {
                    if (is_array($valor3)) {
                        echo '<strong>' . $clave3 . '</strong><br>';
                        foreach($valor3 as $clave4 => $valor4) {
                            if (is_array($valor4)) {
                                echo '<strong>' . $clave4 . '</strong><br>';
                                foreach($valor4 as $clave5 => $valor5) {
                                    echo '<strong>' . $clave5 . '</strong><br>';
                                    echo $clave5 . ' -> ' . $valor5 . '<br>';
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                echo $clave4 . ' -> ' . $valor4 . '<br>';
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        echo $clave3 . ' -> ' . $valor3 . '<br>';   
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                echo $clave2 . ' -> ' . $valor2 . '<br>';   
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        echo $clave1 . ' -> ' . $valor1 . '<br>';
    }
}
```